# Are the Geekbench multicore scores done using embarrassingly parallel processes?

Tags: cpu, performance, multi-core, benchmarking, parallel-processing

For each processor, the benchmarks at geekbench.com present both a single-core and multi-core score. For example, [this 64-core processor](https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/2674) has a single-core score of 1220 and a multi-core score of 23688. Is the Geekbench multicore benchmark measured by (Case 1) running multiple single-core benchmarks on multiple cores at once ([embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel))? Or, (Case 2) is a single set of benchmarks run, which might involve processes that do not parallelize so well.

For the 64-core CPU example above, the multi-core performance falls short of the 64x1220 = 78080 score that we might expect from linear scaling of the single core behavior. In Case 2, this difference might be expected due to the lack of perfect parallelizability of the benchmarks. However, in Case 1, the difference must be inherent to the processor, which cannot offer full single-core performance on all the cores simultaneously, presumably due to thermal management issues.

Comment: From the primatelabs support forums, one response indicates that the tests are "massively parallel" http://support.primatelabs.com/discussions/geekbench/59487-are-the-multi-core-tests-embarrassingly-parallel  Another thread says something to the opposite: "The multi-core benchmark does involve some communication between cores and access to memory". from: http://support.primatelabs.com/discussions/geekbench/26089-why-is-not-dualcore-twice-as-fast-as-singlecore  So, this doesn't seem to provide a clear resolution.

Answer (score 1):

There is much more to multicore than just a combination of unrelated CPUs. Let me mention some (in random order)

- Multiple cores might (and most often will) share a memory controller - this implies, that on multicore benchmarks RAM bandwidth might be a limiting factor
- Multiple cores might or might not share a significant part of on-die cache. This implies, that a loop that fits in the cache if the other cores are idle might not fit if all cores work. This can cause orders of magnitude differences.
- In all modern CPUs, the thermal management is a very hard problem to get right. Most CPU designs will clock a single core much higher, if other cores are idle and the total fits inside thermal constraints. Per definition this implies slower clock speed on full multicore benchmarks.
- Multiple cores might ore might not have a different number of bus hops to RAM. Again this has implications on multicore vs. single core performance.

The gist of this comes down to: Do not expect linear scalability in COTS multicore CPUs.

Comment: I think that this is a great answer to the second paragraph. Thank you! But what about the title question: should the Geekbench bechmarks provide linear scaling for a processor that did happen to offer that?

Comment: Last sentence of my answer: *Do not expect linear scalability in COTS multicore CPUs.* So the answer is no,

Comment: Right, but the question is: are the Geekbench tests embarrassingly parallel. I think that the answer is yes, but that exact linear scaling is not typically seen for most CPUs. For many CPUs, approximate single-core scaling is seen, picking a random example: https://browser.geekbench.com/processors/1715

Comment: I have no sufficient information on the benchmark process - but your example seems to be impossible: 3916 vs 3790 with a 3.4GHz vs. 4.0Ghz clock. Most likely the single core and multicore benchmark come from different machines - with the same CPU, but e.g. different RAM timings.

Comment: That example has single-core=979, multi-core=3790. So, the multi-core is about 3.9x the single-core score, which makes sense for a 4-core processor that doesn't slow down too much when all of the cores are active. I'm not quite sure how the different clock speeds come into play.

Comment: One core active: 4.0GHz, all cores active 3.4 GHz. So total should be around 979*3.4/4.0*4 which is 3328.6